# How to remove a curried Event Listener

Tags: javascript

I have an `addEventListener` that is using a curried function so then I can use the parameters of the function.

```
const curryFunction = (product) => {
  return function curry(e) {
    //do stuff here
  }
}

const addEvent = (product) => {
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', curryFunction(product))
}
```

but I want to be able to remove it, I've looked up similar questions to this on stack overflow, but as they didn't have this specific case they didn't seem to work. I tried

```
document.getElementById('button').removeEventListener('click', curryFunction(product)) // just didn't do anything
document.getElementById('button').removeEventListener('click', curryFunction()) // gave me error
document.getElementById('button').removeEventListener('click', curry()) // gave me error
```

along with the similarities such as

```
document.getElementById('button').removeEventListener('click', curryFunction)
document.getElementById('button').removeEventListener('click', curryFunction(product))//this one was nested inside a function so I wouldn't get an error || product had the same value as the product in the addEvent(product)
document.getElementById('button').removeEventListener('click', curry)
document.getElementById('button').removeEventListener('click', curry(e))//this one was nested inside a function so I wouldn't get an error with the e
```

and none of them worked, so what are the ways to do either

1. Remove a curried eventListener function or
2. Have a eventListener without `.bind()` because that didn't work either

Comment: Did you try: `const myListener = curryFunction(product); doc.addEventListener('click', myListener); doc.removeEventListener('click', myListener)`? This is similar to the `setTimeout` where you have to keep a reference to the "thing" you bound in order to remove it later.

Comment: No I did not try that let me do that really quickly

Comment: Neverminde @GACy20 would you mind making an answer so I can get you the reputation you deserve lol, it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `removeEventListener` requires a reference to the same exact "object", because it will use object identity to see which listener to remove.

The `curryFunction` function creates a new instance every time it is called, so you have to keep track of that function in order to remove it later on:

```
var myListener = undefined;
const addEvent = (product) => {
  // Store the reference to the listener somewhere
  myListener = curryFunction(product);
  document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', myListener)

}

// later on use myListener to remove the listener

document.getElementById('button').removeEventListener('click', myListener)
```

Note that in this case if `addEvent` is called twice without calling `removeEventListener` in between you will lose the reference. So either you should check, before adding a new listener, that you don't have already one in place/you remove the existing one or you can use an array/object to keep track of multiple listeners at the same time.

Comment: This is a great explanation of it, thank you so much for your effort :D